# Input doesn't work in sweet alert2 in react

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert2

I write this code in react using sweet alret2 but when I wanna write something in input it doesn't work and I can't type anything in input box:

```
  const handleEdit = async (value) => {
    const { value: email } = await Swal.fire({
      title: "please write your name.",
      input: "text",
      confirmButtonText: "ok",
      cancelButtonText: "cancle",
      showCancelButton: true,
      showCloseButton: true,
    });
  };
  <MenuItem
      id={`${params.userId}`}
       onClick={(e) => {
          handleEdit(e.target.id);
          }}
          disableRipple
        >
          <DriveFileRenameOutlineIcon sx={{ mr: "7px" }} />
          change
        </MenuItem>
```

I wanna type in input box but I can't. what is the problem?